# How to measure RSSI in ndnSIM?

Tags: ns-3, rssi, ndnsim

I am a master's graduate student in computer science. I am researching CCN (Contents Centric Network), and I am trying to implement the experiment in ndnSIM of ns-3.

In my experiment, I would like to implement route steering by RSSI value, but RSSI measurement is not implemented by default in ndnSIM.

I think I need to make modifications in the header and reference parts, not in the experimental executable file (.cpp), but it's too difficult and I don't know where to start.

Any method is fine, so I would like to learn the knowledge that can be applied to measuring the RSSI value and outputting it to a terminal or text file (or other file), and changing the path in an executable file.

I look forward to.